# How to change position of bootstrap timepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, position, timepicker

[screenshot of timepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfAXo.png)

The timepicker is located on the right and the right part of it is not visible.
Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var timepickerConfig =  {
        showMeridian: false,
        minuteStep: 1
    };
    jQuery('#tp_${name}').timepicker(timepickerConfig);
});
```

I've tried :

```
placement: "left"
```

and

```
orientation: "left"
```

and

```
pickerPosition: "left"
```

This is the library: [jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Asking “is it possible”-questions is not something you should do here (because the “correct” answer to such a question would be either Yes or No, and you probably want a little more than that, right?) So start with describing what you want to achieve (use your words, instead of just pointing to an image), and tell us what you tried so far.

Comment: @CBroe changed question.

Comment: what is the timepicker library so we can see the api?

Comment: @jenson-button-event http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: right, so it appears no option for placement. you could use css, inspect the class or id of the picker container and use a `margin-right: 100px` or similar. alternatively increase the width of your input. the picker is already aligned left, but has not enough space relative to the width of your control

Comment: @jenson-button-event thanks. I fixed it in css.